# GOOGLE SHEETS - If a cell contains text from a list... display corresponding text`

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have
a list of addresses in column A, List of states in Column D.

I would like to search the text in a cell, if it contains a certain state then return the state value based on the List.

Please see screenshot

Thank you in advance for the help!

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JyEP.png)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f5-poZ3osC67r77IcfUUvlH5g3kEqvJCjy_aU5X-0A0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below formula-

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(FILTER($D$2:$D$5,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$2:$D$5,A2))),"No State Found"))
```

As per your given sheet, try below formula-

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A2," ")),"select Col1 where Col1 matches '" & TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE(),$E$2:$E) & "'",0),"No state found")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response - looks like there is an overflow into the next cell down with that formula. Any way to keep it relevant to just that one cell to display the correct state? @Harun24hr

Comment: Because my address contains "sa" in it - the formula is also returning SA for the state in the next cell down

Comment: Then try- `=INDEX(IFERROR(FILTER($D$2:$D$5,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$2:$D$5,A2))),"No State Found"),1)`

Comment: hmm it works up till a point then displays the wrong value. Cant add an image here but it is in the spreadsheet link above. Thanks again for the time/help.

Comment: Check my edited answer.